# Postgres: Default for column (string) cannot be cast automatically to type enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, enums

I have a `status` column in a table that I want to be an enum. Originally I created that field as an integer, thinking that I would use the built in Rails enum functionality. Turns out that requires at least Rails 4.1, but I am using 4.0 and the process of upgrading is going to take some time.

But thinking about how this all works, I realized that I can have **either** an ActiveRecord enum **or** a postgres enum, not both. I thought that in the long term having a more explicit postgres enum would be best. So, I wrote a migration to convert the `status` column from an integer to an enum.

```
execute "CREATE TYPE status_options AS ENUM ('pending', 'declined', 'approved');"
change_column :site_applications, :status, "status_options USING status::status_options"
```

But, I get this error:

```
PG::CannotCoerce: ERROR:  cannot cast type integer to status_options
ALTER TABLE "site_applications" ALTER COLUMN "status" TYPE status_options USING status::status_options
```

Everything that I have seen so far in my searchings tells me that **should have worked**, but it doesn't. I thought maybe the problem is that I just can't go from integer to enum. So be it. My solution was to first convert the column to a string and *then* try to convert it to enum.

```
change_column :site_applications, :status, :string
execute "CREATE TYPE status_options AS ENUM ('pending', 'declined', 'approved');"
change_column :site_applications, :status, "status_options USING status::status_options"
```

And that gives me the following error:

```
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  default for column "status" cannot be cast automatically to type status_options
ALTER TABLE "site_applications" ALTER COLUMN "status" TYPE status_options USING status::status_options
```

That led me to believe that this had something to do with the default value, so I tried specifying the default in the `change_column` declaration:

```
change_column :site_applications, :status, :string, default: "pending"
```

That successfully changes the column to a string with a default of "pending", but `change_column` fails with the same "default for column" error.

I realize that I could simply drop the column all together and then recreate it exactly how I want, but at this point it's a matter of posterity. Why the heck can't I convert a column from integer or string to enum? Anyone?

**UPDATE WITH ACCEPTED ANSWER**

Based on Gary's answer down there, this is the migration that worked.

```
def up
  execute "ALTER TABLE site_applications ALTER status DROP DEFAULT;"
  execute "CREATE TYPE status_options AS ENUM ('pending', 'declined', 'approved');"
  change_column :site_applications, :status, "status_options USING status::status_options", default: "pending"
end

def down
  change_column :site_applications, :status, :string, default: "pending"
  execute "DROP TYPE status_options;"
end
```

Comment: Can you show the results of a \dt site_applications in PSQL.  Because the message sounds like there is a default value set against the column.  You might need to remove the default while you make the change and then add back a default of the appropriate type afterwards.

Comment: @Gary I think you are absolutely right, but I can't **for the life of me** figure out what type of default to set so that it can be switched to an enum. But, I did the `\dt schema.site_applications` and this is what it returned: `schema | site_applications | table | eliduke`

Comment: sorry, It should have been \d instead of \dt

Comment: Oh, ok. Here's that: `status | integer | not null default 0`. But I'm not surprised by that, really, because when I tried to convert the integer to enum, I got error `cannot cast type integer to status_options`. So, I thought that since an enum is sort of variant of a string that I would first convert it to a string and then convert to enum. And THAT is when I got the `default for column` error. At one point I even tried converting the integer to a string and setting the default on the string column to nil and then converting to enum. That failed too with the same error.

Comment: In that case you want to issue a `alter table schema.site_applications alter status drop default` to remove the default entirely.  convert the type, then `alter table schema.site_applications alter status set default 'pending'::status_options'` not entirely sure of the default enum syntax.

Comment: That was the winner! Thank you so much, @Gary. If you want to write up an answer, I will pick that as the answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to remove the default value from the column prior to the change as the default is set to a value that is valid for the old column type but incompatible with the new type.

```
alter table schema.site_applications alter status drop default
```

Then you can change the column type.  Finally once the new column type is applied, you can add a new default against the table.

```
alter table schema.site_applications alter status set default 'pending'::status_options
```